# Bash script to copy files from "Downloads" folder

Tags: bash

I have created a script that will check if the file is in Downloads folder. Then it will copy the file to the location needed and then rename this to something else.

I have done this by:

```
if [ -f /home/$username/Downloads/Framework\ Code\ Note\ $1.txt ]; then 
cp /home/$username/Downloads/Framework\ Code\ Note\ $1.txt /home/$username/Documents/TASKS/Framework/$3/$2/
mv Framework\ Code\ Note\ $1.odt Framework\ Code\ Note\ $2.odt
else
    echo "The file does not exist yet Download the latest notes from your email"
fi
```

The problem is I usually have different versions of the same file name and need to download the latest file from the email. So the names become Framework Code Note 10.txt, Framework Code Note 10(1).txt Framework Code Note 10(2).txt etc...

How can I modify this to only pull the latest Notes from my Downloads folder (if possible)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the latest version of your file (i.e. `Framework Code Note 10(X).txt`, where X is the greatest), you can use the following :

```
IFS=$'\n' MYARRAY=($( printf "%s\n" "/path/to/downloads/Framework Code Note $1"*.txt | sort -nr -t '(' -k 2 ))
cp "${MYARRAY[0]}" /my/destination/folder
```

When you break it down :

- `printf "%s\n" "/path/to/downloads/Framework Code Note $1"*.txt` finds all files in the downloads directory that start by "Framework Code Note Y", where Y is the value of `$1`. That way, `Framework Code Note 10(X).txt` and `Framework Code Note 10.txt` are matched.
- `sort -nr -t '(' -k 2` sorts the resulting files in numerical order (`-n`) considering the 2nd column (`k 2`). The separator for each column is '(' (`-t '('`), and the result is then reversed so that the first result has the highest number (`-r`)
- The output of the command is stored in `$MYARRAY`. You then extract the highest version number when reading the 1st element of the array
- `IFS=$'\n':` sets Internal Field Separator to `\n`, only for this line. This variable is used by bash to know how arguments are separated, its default value is `\n\t`.This means that when we allocate values to `$MYARRAY`, if a name contains an empty space, it would be treated as a separator (i.e, if you have only `Framework Code Note 10.txt`, `Framework` will be stored to `MYARRAY[0]`, `Code` to `MYARRAY[1]`, etc). As the attribution is done inline, `$IFS` is restored to its default value after execution

Comment: Don't use `ls`, use `printf "%s\n" "Framework Code Note $1"*` -- `ls` is often aliased to use color codes or trailing "filetype" characters. You need the `*` *outside* the quotes, or else it won't be recognised as a globbing character. You need to quote `"${MYARRAY[0]}"` to keep the word with whitespace together as a single word.

Comment: @Ploutox, thanks for this. But it is not picking up the name of the file it shows this cp: cannot stat `Framework Code Note 10*': No such file or directory

Comment: @Raj the issue is due to @glennjackman edit. There is a syntax error with the printf and the `*` character. I'll edit my answer when I correct this

Comment: @glennjackman My bad I corrected it. Thanks for the insight about the `printf` use (it was a missing double quote)

Comment: @Ploutox Sorry still getting the same error I did previously add the missing quote should have mentioned it: cp: cannot stat `Framework Code Note 10*': No such file or directory

Comment: @Raj What is the output of `printf "%s\n" "Framework Code Note $1"*` when you execute it in your download folder ?

Comment: @Ploutox it returns various pdf, odt and txt files that are of similar name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56540/discussion-between-ploutox-and-raj).